# Javascript: email string array cannot be found

Tags: javascript, typescript, string

Im trying to write a basic ts function to set an array of authorized emails, but checking it with these logs

```
export const createSection = async (section: Section): Promise<Section> => {
  const newSectionRef = await setDoc(
    doc(sectionsCollection, section.id),
    sectionToJson(section),
  );

  //now update the authorizedEmails
  const sectionRef = doc(sectionsCollection, section.id);

  console.log('section', section);
  console.log('sectionEmails', section.authorizedEmails);

  //make an array to held everyones email
  const emails = section.authorizedEmails!.map((email) => email);
  console.log('Forced mapped emails:', emails);

  console.log('Direct property access:', section['authorizedEmails']);

  console.log('Stringified:', JSON.stringify(section));

  const clonedSection = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(section));
  console.log('Cloned authorized emails:', clonedSection.authorizedEmails);

  const testSection = {
    id: 'test-id',
    crn: 'test-crn',
    teacherId: 'test-teacherId',
    teacherName: 'test-teacherName',
    courseId: 'test-courseId',
    students: [],
    sectionNumber: 'test-sectionNumber',
    courseName: 'test-courseName',
    sectionName: 'test-sectionName',
    authorizedEmails: ['test1@email.com', 'test2@email.com'],
  };

  console.log('Test section:', testSection.authorizedEmails);

  await setDoc(
    sectionRef,
    {
      authorizedEmails: emails,
    },
    { merge: true },
  );

  console.log('email', section.authorizedEmails);
  console.log('emails', emails);
  return { ...section };
};
```

When the array is visible and present when the section is printed, but disappears when called from anything that uses .authorizedEmails.

Any ideas?

Comment: `createSection` is asynchronous. Are you sure you are awaiting it everywhere where you use it?